# Intrinsic Reach for a Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, embeddings

The [*reach*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reach_(mathematics)) of a set $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is the supremum of all $r \geq 0$ such that for all $y\in X^c$ with $dist(y,X)<r$ there is a unique $x\in X$ with $dist(y,x)= dist(y,X)$.

**My question:** If $X$ is an $m$-dimensional $C^{\infty}$ Riemannian manifold, is there an intrinsic definition of the reach, i.e., one that does not involve an ambient space?

**I know** that the reach is bounded from below by the inverse of the curvature. Furthermore, by [Whitney embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem), $X$ is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$, so there is always an ambient space to be found. However, it is not clear whether all embeddings will have the same reach.

Comment: Regarding the final question: for any $r > 0$ I can give you an isometric embedding of $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}^{k+d}$, $k,d$ arbitrary, so that the reach of $X = \mathbb{R}^k$ is precisely $r$. So no.

Comment: @WillieWong what is the counter example?

Comment: Ok curve it "around" one dimension, and that's an isometry. However, it doesn't preserve the manifold structure (specifically the curvature). Maybe I'm using the wrong term "embedding"?

Comment: The curvature you are referring to is the extrinsic curvature; that is not, in general, fully determinable from the intrinsic quantities of the manifold. (It depends on the choice of the isometric embedding.)

Comment: @AmirSagiv Just consider different embeddings of a circle.

Comment: The simplest higher dimensional counterexample is that of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the flat metric. In general, if the codimension of the embedding is sufficiently large, the embedding becomes flexible, and it is possible, if laborious, to show that, for *any* Riemannian manifold, $r$ can be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: @DeaneYang: Take $M$ and embed it into $\mathbb{R}^k$ by Whitney. Fix a point $p$ on $M$ and a tangent vector $v\in T_pM$. "Fold" $\mathbb{R}^k$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ so that $p$ lies "on the fold" and the fold is "perpendicular to $v$". So you just need to add 1 more dimension to the ambient space to do the construction.

Comment: @DeaneYang Thanks. Is there a reference to it?